# QtWebkit crashes Python on Windows

Tags: javascript, python, qtwebkit

I am trying to scrape a website that uses javascript. I am using the following code:

```
import os
import sys
import re
import requests
import mechanize
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html
import pandas as pd
import time

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()


    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

def read_page(url):
    r = Render(url)
    result = r.frame.toHtml()
    text = str(result.toAscii())
    html_source = html.fromstring(text)
    return text, html_source

for url in urls:
    text, html_source = read_page(url)
```

After reading successfully the first url, on the second url it displays the following message and python.exe crashes.

```
content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem.
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::onlineStateChanged(bool) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged(bool)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationUpdateComplete() to QNetworkConfigurationManager::updateCompleted()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but I've been playing around with web scraping recently and I ran into your problem. The problem is you're trying to run several QApplications, which doesn't work, (i don't really completely understand why though :/).
You should try doing something like whats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863412/how-to-use-qtwebkit-in-python-threads).

So basically instead of trying to start a few Qapps, just make the one Qapp and have it load everything.